# suppress dialog box when downloading files using flash actionscript3 filereference class

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, download, filereference

I'm trying to set up flash's FileReference class to download files from a publicly accessible web directory to a specific location on my hard drive, without having to use the browse dialogue that is automatically triggered using the download() method. Anyone know how to predefine a location for the downloaded file so I don't have to trigger the dialogue?

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/FileReference.html#download()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they don't allow you to do that because it can be a security risk. You would be able to silently overwrite a user's files or install trojans and such stuff. I don't think there's a way around it.

Comment: Hmmm...well, I'm trying to make an application that downloads an entire folder to the desktop - I understand the security risk thing (although this application is only for our company's internal use). it'd be fine to just have to browse once I guess, but having to do that for like 500 files is a little over the top. I guess I'll research how to automate a zipping of that folder, and the download of a self-extracting zip file.

Comment: With AIR you can do more stuff on the user's machine because AIR apps are more like desktop applications. Might be another way to achieve what you need to.

Comment: yeah - that's what I'm gathering. I'll take a look at that.